# Yeoman Jekyllrb generator hangs part-way through scaffolding

Tags: ruby, node.js, jekyll, yeoman

I'm new to Jekyll but not to Yeoman. I've installed Jekyll and the Jekyllrb generator for the first time recently and successfully created a new boilerplate Jekyll site with `jekyll new my-awesome-site`, but I haven't had any success with the generator. It works fine during the options selection stage and through to `bundle install`, but hangs after installing all the gems and doesn't move on to the next stage in the sequence:

```
  create .gitignore
  create .gitattributes
  create Gruntfile.js
  create package.json
  create .bowerrc
  create bower.json
  create Gemfile
  create .jshintrc
  create .csslintrc
  create .editorconfig

  Running bundle install to install the required gems.
  Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
  Resolving dependencies...
  Using blankslate 2.1.2.4
  [ ... ]
  Using jekyll 1.4.3
  Using bundler 1.7.3
  Your bundle is complete!
  Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

It doesn't cancel the task at this point or show an error message, it just stops and never resumes. I've tried installing a new version of Ruby and updating everything I could think of, but no joy. Any idea what's causing this issue?

**Dev environment:**

- [Jekyllrb generator](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) 1.2.1
- OSX Mavericks
- Ruby 2.1.1,  rbenv 0.4.0,  bundler 1.7.3,  gem 2.2.2,  jekyll 1.4.3
- Node 0.10.22,  npm 2.0.2,  yo 1.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was caused by special characters (spaces and/or parentheses) in the directory path name, which was `/Users/username/Dropbox (Personal)/dev/testers/jekyll/`

The problem can be fixed by running the generator in a different directory, renaming the directory, or escaping the characters in the generator.